# Unemployment benefits for a limited residence permit holder in Germany

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit, unemployment-benefits

My wife joined me in Germany last month. I tried to search online whether she is entitled for unemployment benefit but I got a mixture of opinions.

She joined me via the family reunification route. Her residence permit (after she receives it) will probably end after 4 years, similarly to mine. Is she entitled for unemployment benefits? if yes, a link or guidelines about the procedure will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if she is entitled, but the process to claim unemployment benefit is to turn up at the local Agentur für Arbeit and register.  It is helpful to speak some German, but my experience is that they will speak slowly if you ask them to.  It is an altogether more civilized experience than I remember from the UK in the 80's (and it has only got worse in the UK).

They ought to know if she is entitled or not (but a definitive answer with references would be good, so you can argue if they say "not", but actually she is).

Answer (score 1):

It is called Unemployment insurance and requires 12 monthly payments as a minimum.